# Indicating Invalid Value with Reason

Tags: rest, http-status-code-400, http-response-codes

I am designing an endpoint that a client will hit to register a tenant with an application; these tenants are represented as subdomains (`<subdomain>.alex.com`). I want to reserve all subdomains with length <= 4 (for example they can only be registered for select clients). What is the "right" HTTP error code to return to the user if they choose a subdomain <= 4 characters?

400 seems okay, but I am wondering if there is better.

One thought would be [422](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2):

```
  422 Unprocessable Entity
  The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
  understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
  415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
  syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request)
  status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
  instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML
  request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but
  semantically erroneous, XML instructions.
```

Comment: "semantically erroneous" sounds like a good reason to use 422.

Answer (score 0):

The 422 code seems good for what you want to do, however I would also consider 403, which could also apply. I would prefer 403 over 422 for a couple of reasons, i.e. the code definition for 403 states that automatic repeats shouldn't be issued, or even just because is a more commonly used status code. However this is just my opinion. In both cases I think the server should also send a message explaining the problem, along with the status code.